# Detect if current thread is ExecutorService thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I want to ensure all methods of my class (updater service) are called within the `ExecutorService`'s thread (provided there's even a single thread). The order of the methods is not given so those that are public might get called from both the `Executor`'s thread and some other threads, mostly GUI thread.

My code:

```
  // Instantiated lazy using synchronized getter - I decided not to bother with shared locks
  private ExecutorService executor;
  /**
   * Provides compatibility between calls from executor thread pool and other threads. 
   * No matter the thread from which you call this method, the callback will be executed
   * within the loop. Proper events will be raised in the loop thread as well, so
   * mind to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater if event involves GUI operations.
   * @param callback
   * @throws Exception 
   */
  protected void runInExecutorIfNeeded(Callable callback) throws Exception {
    // Already in executor thread
    if(Thread.currentThread() == /* ??? */)
      callback.call();
    // Not in executor thread, go to executor thread and call callback there
    else
      getExecutor().submit(callback);
  }
```

I have already done a similar thing in Swing - for methods like `changeApplicationTrayIcon` I simply checked if I'm in GUI thread and if not, I used `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

So, how do I check if current code is running in Executor's thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you provide an implementation of a [ThreadFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) to your implementation of an ExecutorService (e.g. a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)), you could record the threads created by the factory (either by reference or id) and perform a lookup against that ThreadFactory later on in order to determine if they've been created by the factory, and thus an executor thread

Comment: Oh, I am little confused. The executor service does not use event loop to execute events/actions one by one? It might just be I was not even the thread ExecutorService what I intended to use. But of course that's not your fault, I guess I'll look into it and accept your answer.

Comment: @TomášZato The executor uses an event loop, running a thread created by the ThreadFactory.  You could create a sub-class of Thread and just check for `Thread.currentThread() instanceof MyThread`

Comment: I have not tested it yet but I implemented ThreadFactory so that it makes one thread, which is then exposed through getter. I use that to do do check. Unfortunately, it added another private property (the factory instance) to the updater class.